# can we use fedex shipping method for india store by inbuilt magento fedex functionality?

Tags: shipping, fedex

We need Fedex shipping method for our India store. I tried to configure it through admin panel by putting all settings but it is producing default Fedex shipping method error. Can anyone let me know that Fedex shipping method can be used for India specific store? It would definitely worked for US and Canada but for other countries don't know. Can any one let me out from this issues?

Comment: yes you need to upgrade your fedex api for india.

Comment: Download latest API pack from fedex site and used GDE folder. In this API for India

Answer (score 3):

Update the wsdl files in Magento/Fedex/Carrier.php file

In order for the India to India domestic shipping to work you need to add in a PurposeOfShipment type to the request. This line is not standard in Magento's code for Fedex shipping. That line will be added into CustomsClearanceDetail header as a child under CommercialInvoice then a line under that is Purposewhich can have any value that PurposeOfShipment has.

Here is an example of the request I used that returned proper shipping estimates for India to India shipping.

```
'CustomsClearanceDetail' => array(
     'CommercialInvoice' => array(
       'Purpose' => "SOLD"
    )
),
```

The rates for some reason only work with production keys for me.Try the production keys if you are also having some problem with test.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Magento 1.9 .Can you please suggest which file i have to edit as in Magento 1.9 there is no such file "carrier.php" in /magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model

Comment: My credentials correct, i have two store in single magento, store 1 display Fedex shipping cost, but store 2 not displaying shipping cost, how can i solve this issue?